# Why does my bash command have a "%" sign instead of a "$" and why won't it work?

Tags: bash, terminal, macos

I need to use my terminal to make an edit allowing me to fully access CUPS (to add a printer to my computer).  Yet, my bash symbol is a "%" sign not a the typical "$" symbol... and it won't take edits.  Can this be fixed and how?

I'm running Big Sur on a new Mac mini.

Comment: `and it won't take edits` - how do you edit it?

Comment: What exactly are you running and what do you mean by not working?

Comment: It's unclear what your actual issue is. It shouldn't matter much what your prompt is, but depending on what shell you're using, different shell startup files may be in effect. Let us know what the actual issue is (because it's most definitely not the character used as your prompt).

Comment: I need to access the web interface/administration tab on CUPS to add a printer.  The command suggested is "cupsctl WebInterface=yes"

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?  I've tried the suggestions and nothing works...

Comment: You can't add a printer via the GUI?

Answer (score 3):

Your "bash" is actually zsh.  Newer macos versions use zsh by default which will have the `%` symbol on your prompt by default.  You can change it with:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Comment: Ok.  So I do see I have ZSH.  But I ran that and the bash is still a "%"

Comment: Further, the command I need to use... "cupsctl WebInterface=yes" is not accepted.

Comment: Try `echo $0` and post the exact output. Also `echo :$PS1:` and post the exact output. And post the exact output from your `cupsctl` command -- "not accepted" is no help to us.

Comment: No output from either command.